# ASP.NET MVC 3 Views and Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have a model, called Organisation and the model is stored in an assembly called Model. There is a requirement to insert an organisation and update an organisation.

Couple of questions:

When inserting a new organisation, I want to ensure that the organisation doesn't already exist so I've inserted some remote validation. I then bind the model to the insert view.

Now, when I'm creating the update view should I use a different view model which removes the remote validation for duplicate organisation names? If so, I can't use my base Organisation model for the update view, so do I then need to create 2 different views, one for insert and one for update? If this is the case, there is going to be 2 views that are basically the same but just use different models.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific scenario the validation that no other organization with the same name exists seems valid for both the insert and update case so you could reuse the same view model.

However validating that the name does not exists when updating a organization must have extra because if the user does not change the organization name then at least one record on the database has that name, the one being updated, and the validation should ignore that record.

So if you choose to reuse the view model the validation must perform according to the context of the operation (insert or update).

Comment: I think the issue is that I'm not using a View Model, just the domain entities. I'm thinking that I need to start creating View Models, and then bind the views to a view model rather than the domain entity.

Comment: Generally it's better to use view models because you can tailor them to what the view really needs, but it's not mandatory. As almost everything in software development, it depends on the use case.

Answer (score 0):

- Question 1:  check validation:

If their is something not valid, do this:

```
If(isNotValid()){
    ModelState.AddModelError("Key", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.")
}
```

Key is the field in your view that is incorrect.

- Question 2: Difference between Create / Edit

You should use the same ViewModel, because in your update, they can still change the "Organisation Name" and you should still check if it is unique.

But why should you use a ViewModel just to check the validation? Is there a reason why you can't check the organisation names for uniqueness in your controller and do a ModelState.AddModelError when it is not unique?

A ViewModel is when you have to extend the Page, For Example

```
  public class DashBoardViewModel
  { public List(Of Organisation) Organisation {get;set;}
    public List(Of Staff) Staff{get;set;}
    public List(Of Assignment) Assignments{get;set;}
  }
```

Above would be a fictional DashBoardViewModel where i show all the Organisations, Staff and Assignments.
A ViewModel doesn't contain just one type of object, it contains multiple.

And don't forget, sometimes when you need to add some data to a View, you could just use ViewData or ViewBag, instead of creating a ViewModel.